# iPhone UIView Animation Duration only works instantly

Tags: iphone, uiview, uianimation

This code is being executed in the touchesended method of a subclassed uiview, however it doesn't animate, it just instantly changes the background color. What is wrong?

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:20];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    if (score < .40) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Does it work when you call it from another place, in the subclass or even outside the subclass?

Comment: is changing the color really animatable???

Comment: It's possible, though unlikely, that '20' is being interpreted rather than cast as a float. Try giving it 20.0. Also, double-check that colour is an 'animatable property' in the Apple developer docs.

Comment: Background color is animatable, at least on the CALayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[UIView commitAnimations]` method isn't blocking - so if you call it, it will start animating, but it will execute code after this point instantly.  If you have any code below it that changes the background color, it will break your animations.

If that doesn't work, try animating a different property - I know off the top of my head position & `alpha` are animatable, but I'm uncertain of Color.  (Alpha is just a `float` value, and center is just a `CGPoint`, both of which are primitives, but `UIColor` is a referenced type and UIView may not know how to animate a pointer.)